# why does the this.ActiveMdiChild property return null?

Tags: c#

I have created an array of objects for a child form in C#.NET. Now i need to copy certain controls on the active child form. But the this.ActiveMdiChild property is returning null. Before adding the control the main form is disabled and another form pops up. 
On closing that form the main form and all its controls are enabled and the control is to be added.

//code

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Enabled = false;               
            Properties_Form pf = new Properties_Form(this);
            pf.Location = panel4.Location;
            pf.Show();

//code to paste the control
            PictureBox pbx = new PictureBox();
            NewVDrawWindow nvd = (NewVDrawWindow)this.ActiveMdiChild;
            nvd.Controls["tabControl1"].Controls["tabPage2"].Controls.Add(pbx);

...
}
```

The code to insert the control is written in the same method after the show method coz i'm supposing that the control would return to where it was jumped from.
The code for copying the control is working fine. There is no problem with it.
Is the error there due to disabling n enabling of the form?.Plz help!!

Comment: `ActiveMdiChild` is a parent form's property. If `pictureBox1_Click` is an instance method of a child form, then `this` doesn't refer to the parent form.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the child form's `MdiParent` property in order to make it an MDI child of a form:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Properties_Form pf = new Properties_Form();
    pf.MdiParent = this; // <-- you need this
    pf.Show();
}
```

Comment: Well,I don't want this form as a child form. The child form is another form that is placed on a panel in the main form. Its object is instantiated and I don't understand why the ActiveMdiChild property isn't returning the reference of the object.

Comment: @Shubhra: What do you mean when you say "placed on a panel"? Can you update your question to elaborate that a bit more? If a form has its `MdiParent` form set to parent form, then it's an MDI child.

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            frm2[i] = new NewVDrawWindow();

            frm2[i].MdiParent = this;

            frm2[i].Name += i;

            frm2[i].Text += i;

            frm2[i].Show();

            frm2[i].Parent = panel4;

            frm2[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

}
This is the code for the child form.
And I would like the ActiveMdiChild property to return a reference to the same. But it just returns null.

Comment: @Shubhra: glad you fixed it. Sorry, I forgot about this thread completely.